# Rough mesh lines in partially opaque 3D plots

Tags: plotting, mesh

If I plot a surface with mesh lines, they show up fine (of course). However, if the surface is even just a little transparent, they get quite rough. Compare this to setting the Opacity to 1:

```
  ParametricPlot3D[{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
   4 + Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.99],
   MeshStyle -> Thickness[.005], 
   ImageSize -> 800,
   Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

Here are the results:

[image: rough lines]  [image: smooth lines]

How can I get proper smooth lines and use Opacity at the same time?

UPDATE (Aug. 9, 2014): Wolfram tells me that "this is an issue with rendering transparent 3D objects on Linux systems using Intel graphics hardware." It has to do with "depth peeling".

Comment: Works fine for me on Mathematica 9.0.1 on Mac. What's your version and platform?

Comment: Works great from me also. V9 and V10. Win8.1

Comment: This problem must be oddly system-dependent, because I can reproduce it with Mathematica 9.0.1 on a 2012 MacBook Air running OS X 10.9.3.

Comment: I am using MMA 9.0.1.0 on Linux x86 (32-bit).

Comment: I just downloaded MMA 10.0.0 (on Linux). It has the same problem (though the default colors have changed considerably). I will ask Wolfram about this bug.

Comment: I don't have a windows machine handy to try this at the moment but you might try rasterization. Something like `Rasterize[pic,RasterSize->1000,ImageSize->500]`. The result is non-rotatable but, in my experience, yields a very nice image which is quite suitable as a standalone image or for export.

Comment: Rasterize gives the same image (on my system, at least). BTW, my Linux is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answet, but an extended comment with graphics.

Running V9 on OS X, your code with `PlotStyle -> Opacity[.8]`, gives me this:

[image: torus]

I experience no noticeable performance hit. What's not to like about it? Well, I'd add `Mesh -> Full` to fill in the missing mesh circle at `u = 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the missing mesh part!

Comment: How does one get a Full Mesh while also using a non-default number of lines? Without Full, it will not give the lines at 0 (or 2Pi). I have posted this as a regular question at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54744/how-does-one-get-mesh-lines-at-0-in-parametricpolt3d

Comment: For completeness: The answer to that question is to use BoundaryStyle (see the answer to the above post).