# How does one get Mesh lines at 0 in ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, mesh

The following is in the documentation (MMA 10) under ParametricPlot3D -> Options -> Mesh :

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
  Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> 10]
```

You'll see that the lines for u=0 and for v=0 are missing. These can be restored by using `Mesh->Full`, but then the number of lines will be the default, 15. I'd also like to have the number of lines be different in the two directions, with each one containing 0, but Mesh->{Full,10}, e.g., gives an error. Here is the image in the documentation:

[image: missing mesh lines]

**Update:**  While the answer below works as requested, it does not work for tubes. See this example:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
  Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> 10, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Tube[.03], MeshStyle -> Tube[.03]]
```

[image]

Comment: Russ, thanks for the accept. Regarding `Tube` issue, your code works as expected in Version 9.0.1.0 but not in Version 10. Please see the update to my answer for a suggestion to get the same result in Version 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `BoundaryStyle -> ...` (because `0` lies at the boundary of  `u` and `v` ranges:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u],  Sin[v]},
       {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize->500,
       Mesh -> 10, BoundaryStyle ->Directive[Thick, Red]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Rendering mesh lines as `Tube`s

In Version 9.0.1.0

```
 ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], Sin[v]},
    {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> 10, 
    BoundaryStyle -> Tube[.03], MeshStyle -> Tube[.03]]
```

gives

[image]

In Version 10, you can post-process `Line`s into `Tube`s to get a similar result:

```
 ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], Sin[v]}, 
       {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> 10,
       BoundaryStyle -> Automatic, MeshStyle ->Automatic]/. Line->Tube
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Would you agree this is a bug in Version 10?

Comment: @Russ, not sure it is a bug; especially because the usage of `Tube[.03]` as a `Directive` is -- I think -- undocumented.