# How to include Thickness for surface in Contour Plot?

Tags: plotting

```
ContourPlot3D[ f(x,y,z) ==0, {x,xmin,xmax},{y,ymin,ymax},{z,zmin,zmax},ContourStyle-> Thickness[2.0]]
```

Like in this case Thickness does not appear to Show:

```
b1 = ContourPlot3D [{.005 x^2 + .0055 y^2 + .0031 z^2 == 1}, {x, -20, 
   20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -15.5, 15.5}, ContourStyle -> Thickness[4]]
```

Also how can Contour Lines be shown in Tube Style? 
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55021/4999

Comment: `Line -> Tube[#, 0.1]` or `MeshStyle -> Tube[.1]` & substitute desired radius for `0.1`? See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54744/how-does-one-get-mesh-lines-at-0-in-parametricplot3d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^3 + y^2 - z^2
```

You can use the (afaik undocumented) option `"Extrusion"`:

```
ContourPlot3D[f[x,y,z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   "Extrusion" ->. 2]
```

[image]

You can also use `Extrusion -> .2` or `Method ->{"Extrusion" -> .2}`.

Alternatively, use `PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"`:

```
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
  PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"]
```

[image]

To make the mesh lines into `Tube`s you can post-process:

```
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[.5, Orange], 
  MeshStyle -> Red] /. Line[x_] :> Tube[x, .03]
```

[image]

or use (also undocumented, afaik) option setting `Tube[radius]` for `MeshStyle`:

```
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 ContourStyle -> Opacity[.5, Orange], MeshStyle -> Tube[.03]]
```

[image]

**Note:** The last two pictures are obtained using v9 (windows 10). Can't run the same code on v12 on free Wolfram Cloud because of cloud credit limits.

Comment: Thanks. It appears Extrusion-> ..   works better.  Next further on..in the given example how do we show with ContourPlot3D {x = xcon, y=ycn, z=zcon } Cartesian planes sections in Tube PlotStyle when so desired?

Comment: @Narasimham, "further on..." part sounds like a good new question.

Comment: OK I shall give a new question..